Will there ever be a fifth Veda?
Will there ever be a fifth Veda? Or will this end at four?

The Itihasas and Puranas are the 5th Veda.

❝Indeed, Rg, Yajur, Sama and Atharva are the names of the four Vedas.
The Itihasas and Puranas are the fifth Veda.❞


Chandogya Upanishad 7.1.4.

